# Attach frequent words in text file

Tags: perl

I have two files. The first contains frequent
word sequences
extracted from a text file

#### a.txt :

```
big pizza
eat big pizza 
...
```

the text file is

#### b.txt :

```
i eat big pizza .my big pizza ...
```

My problem is to add `bbb` between words from each sequence that exist in file `a.txt` and write a new file .
so the result will be

```
i eatbbbbigbbbpizza.my bigbbbpizza...
```

below is my script. It adds `bbb` only between pairs 9f words. How can I correct this?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my ($f1, $f2) = ('a.txt', 'b.txt');
 
open( my $fh, $f1 );

my @seq;

foreach ( <$fh> ) {
  chomp; 
  s/^\s+|\s+$//g; 
  push @seq, $_;      
}
close $fh;
 
open($fh, $f2);

foreach (<$fh> ) {
    foreach my $r (@seq) {   
        my $t = $r =~ s/ /bbb/r; 
        if (/$r/) {
            s/$r/$t/g;
        }
    }
    print ;
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: change my $t = $r =~ s/ /bbb/r;  to my $t = $r =~ s/ /bbb/g;  note g at the end. but it will only solve one problem.

Comment: this don't solve the problem . result will be :  i eat big pizza .my big pizza

Comment: I knew that. it just fixed one problem in your codes (it might just be a typo). i posted the modified codes it worked on your example.

Comment: thanks a lot for , this helped me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the modified code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my ($f1, $f2) = ('a.txt', 'b.txt');

open(my $fh, $f1);
my @seq;
foreach (<$fh> )
{
  chomp;
  s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
  push @seq, $_;
}
close $fh;

@seq = sort bylen @seq;  # need to sort @seq by length.

open($fh, $f2);
foreach (<$fh> ) {
  foreach my $r (@seq) {
    my $t = $r =~ s/ /bbb/gr; 
    s/$r/$t/g;      # you may need to take care of cases of extra spaces
  }
  print;
}
close $fh;

exit 0;

sub bylen {
   length($b) <=> length($a);
}
```

Comment: how can i make it more fast because I use big files

Answer (score 1):

All that is wrong is your line

```
my $t = $r =~ s/ /bbb/r;
```

This substitution runs just *once*, and so replaces only the first space with `bbb`

You need to use a *global* substitution instead. And while we're changing this line it's best to also replace the space with `\h+`, which matches any amount of "horizontal space", including both tabs and spaces

```
my $t = $r =~ s/\h+/bbb/gr;
```

As it stands your code will find and replacing substrings of other entries in `@seq` if they appear earlier in the array. In this case, that means `big pizza` will be found first and converted to `bigbbbpizza`, after which
`eat big pizza` can no longer be found. You need to first *sort* your array in descending order of length so that longer phrases are found before shorter ones

```
@seq = sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } @seq;
```

Then your program will work a little better